# Get downloaded file from submit button requests python

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to save locally the configuration file from my cable modem. I already have logged into the html admin page of the modem and inside the backup page, there is a button to backup the configuration file. Inside the event, there is a **POST** method on the form that leads to the next url:

https://192.168.1.1/goform/BackUp

The response headers are:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: GoAhead-Webs
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/download 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=cmconfig.cfg // This is the file that is downloaded when I click in the BackUp button
```

And this are the parameters that I pass to the **POST** function:

```
dir: admin/
file: cmconfig.cfg
```

So far, I have this code:

```py
with requests.Session() as s:  # To login into the modem
    pagePostBackUp = 'https://192.168.1.1/goform/BackUp'
    s.post(urlLogin, data=loginCredentials, verify=False, timeout=5)
    dataBackUp = {'dir': 'admin/','file': 'cmconfig.cfg'}
    resultBackUp = s.post(pagePostBackUp, data=dataBackUp, verify=False, timeout=10)
```

What should be the next line to save the `cmconfig.cfg` file locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `resultBackUp` is [a response object](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response), so you could use its `text` or `json` methods.

```
print(resultBackUp.text)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I can't believe that I just needed one more line :-)